# Minibian SSH enabled by default?

Tags: ssh

just wanted to ask if SSH is enabled by default on the Minibian OS? If not, how can I enable it without a monitor or get access to the pi?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [MINIBIAN features](https://minibianpi.wordpress.com/features/) SSH is enabled by default.

- Kernel 3.18.7+ #755
- 13 secs boot (on RPi 2)
- 24 MB RAM used
- 334 MB disk space used
- Fit on 512MB SD Card
- Optimized ext4 file system with swap disabled
- Support for RPi B, RPi B+ and the new RPi 2
- Targeted for embedded or server applications (NAS, Web server,
  electronic applications)
- 100% full compatbile with officiale release
- DHCP client enabled
- SSHD enabled
- root user enabled (default password: raspberry – please change it
  a.s.a.p.)